Angular Mat-stepper how to update the mat-step according the my route link?
Angular Mat-stepper how to update the mat-step according the my route link?
<mat-stepper>
  <mat-step label="Verification">
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step label="Content">
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step label="SecondContent">
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step label="Final">
  </mat-step>
</mat-stepper>

export class StepperComponent{
  private router = inject(Router);
  routerEvents = toSignal(this.router.events);
}

How can i change the active steps when i change my route? also i want them to be disable as It is not clickable for user and this can be done with css pointer-events: none.
For example, when the route is second content then my active steps should be second content.
Thank you

I think you do not need to use css pointer events, but disable the step using the component API.  As well for the current selected tab https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview
